# OpenSSL exe encryption output is not complete

Tags: c#, .net, windows, openssl

I'm facing problem in using OpenSSL.exe version 3.1.0 to encrypt and decrypt user entered password. I'm using the following command format for encryption and decryption.

Encryption:

openssl.exe enc -aes-256-cbc -pbkdf2 -md sha512 -iter 1000 -base64 -A -pass pass:abc@1234

Decryption:

openssl.exe enc -d -aes-256-cbc -pbkdf2 -md sha512 -A -iter 1000 -base64  -pass pass:U2FsdGVkX18+JRgpZj5qGfpy6f8R9VFPRndh+2L7tP4=

After the encryption command, only a part of the encrypted password was displayed. When I pressed Ctrl+C, rest of the content was displayed. When I used the full output in the decryption command, "error reading input file" error is displayed.

Not sure whether the command I'm using is correct or not.